# square-commerce-v1 bring back to window instead of new tab

Tags: square-connect, square

I have the following:

```
var dataParameter = {
    amount_money: {
        amount:        "10",
        currency_code: "USD"
    },

    // Replace this value with your application's callback URL
    callback_url: "https://website.com",

    // Replace this value with your application's ID
    client_id: "sq0123idp-asd89798asd",

    version: "1.3",
    notes: "notes for the transaction",
    options: {
        supported_tender_types: ["CREDIT_CARD","CASH","OTHER","SQUARE_GIFT_CARD","CARD_ON_FILE"]
    }
};

const url =
"square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=" +
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataParameter));
```

Everytime I click this link, it takes me to the correct square app. But then it opens up **website.com** in a new URL.

I'm trying to build a web POS system so that square will just bring me back to the tab it was on originally. Is this possible?

Comment: I have the same question. I hope we get an answer from Square. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the intended way to use this is, and we ran into the same issue (iOS Safari).

Our work-around -- have the callback go to a new endpoint that saves the event (both in `localstorage` and to the server DB via XHR) and then closes itself using Javascript. The tab "under" the current one is the tab we started on, which can then act. It had been polling the `localstorage` and server during the whole transaction to get an update.

We found that even this is fragile though, so ALSO have webhooks registered on the site. For example, in the POS the operator can hit the "X" or similar things to abort the transaction and never trigger the callback. But if something happens upstream we should get the webhook no matter what.

I'd LOVE some insight from Square on better ways to do this. In theory we should be able to use a Universal Link or something.